# How to specify http response header on a react application?

Tags: json, reactjs, http, header

I have [diagnostics.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PPJk.jpg) on public folder in my react app, when I access `http://localhost:3000/diagnostics.json` it shows my json perfectly but I would like to customize/edit the http response headers, how can i do it?

[image]

Comment: I'm assuming you made the app with `create-react-app`?

Comment: @GarrettMotzner yes